# Unfiltered Search Option does not return Accurate Results

Tags: xquery, marklogic, xml-database

In Marklogic, I have to do unfiltered search in order to return the results of the facets. But, this option returns inaccurate results that does not have Search highlight.
I used the searchable Expression in order to get the Path of the Search results,  here is the options that I used:

```
<search-option>unfiltered</search-option>

<searchable-expression>
    /Book//chapter 
</searchable-expression>

<constraint name="chapter">
    <word> 
        <element name="chapter"/>
    </word> 
</constraint> 

<constraint name="Author">
    <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint">
        <element name="author"/>
    </range>
</constraint> </options>
```

Also, I tried to add element query constraint, but it affect the performance of the search query 
This is the search query:

```
search:search("chapter:List of Scenes", $options);
```

Comment: Where do you find you need to run unfiltered searches to get facets ?  I have never heard of that nor can I find it in the docs.

Comment: When I change the Unfiltered Option to Filtered and then tried to get the facet using search:search. It will returns zero results. For example, search:search( "chapter:List of Scenes AND Author:Shakespeare", $options); ... this query will return zero results.

Comment: Are you looking for the phrase "List of Scenes" in the chapter element? If so, I think your search should be `search:search('chapter:"List of Scenes"', $options);` Otherwise, you're doing a chapter constraint with "List" plus separate word queries with "of" and "Scenes".

Comment: Facets count either the number of documents with a lexicon value (usually a value in a range index) or the number of occurrences for a lexicon value. The constraining query for a facet runs unfiltered because lexicon lookups rely entirely on the indexes.  In particular, a facet doesn't count nodes selected dynamically by a searchable expression. In this case, what are the facets and what should they count?

Comment: @ehennum In my case the facet is Author facet and it should count the number of chapters

Comment: @DaveCassel yes I am looking for  "List of Scenes" in the chapter element, so I define the chapter constraint in the options and it was working fine with me until I am shifting to the facets, the facet results return zero if the options are filtered.

Comment: To count chapters, each chapter must be in a separate document or a separate fragment of a fragmented document. Fragments are explained here http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fragments but, where possible, it's usually better to use separate documents and assemble a book if and when needed.

Comment: @ehennum I do  not prefer fragmentation for the database documents. One solution that I was thinking of is making the searchable-expression dynamic. After testing it is work! .. so I change the path of the searchable-expression to <searchable-expression>if($facet) then(/Book) else (Book//chapter )</searchable-expression>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(SO timed out) If you're getting no facets with filtered search, it's because the search didn't produce facets. An unfiltered search can produce facets on text that didn't match the search but was in the same document as a matching indexed term.
Unfiltered searches are not a drop-in replacement for Filtered searches. If the Filtered searches are too slow then you should analyze your queries and data to find where optimizations are appropriate.  Often a compromise is used - optimize a few searches to be fast, then use the results of those to do a 2nd filtered search on a subset of the results as needed to fill in the detail. See https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance.

Comment: The search produce facets depending on the Book element not the chapter element that I am looking for in the searchable-expression. So, the solutions for this are first, fragmentation for the database or second, make this expression dynamic in order to get the facet results